# Mobile app constantly prompts me to “join site” while doing actions on meta

Tags: support, bug, status-declined, stackexchange-mobile-app

With the Screenshot of the Week contests, I find myself visiting Arqade Meta on the mobile app frequently to check out any new posts.

In recent days, the meta version of the constantly prompts me to to join whenever I perform an action. This includes

- Posting a comment
- Upvoting posts

When I do “join”, I am able to do what I do wanted to do, but this happens every time I close and reopen the app.

[image: Meta promoting me to join site]

Versions:

- iOS 13.3.1
- App 1.6.6.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The mobile app is [deprecated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/342028/370674), and won't be receving any new updates:

> We are not providing any further support for the mobile apps. There will not be any more builds made for either the Android or the iOS app (even for breaking bugs). We encourage all mobile users to use the responsive website. We hope to continue to incrementally improve the user experience for mobile users. - [Yaakov Ellis](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/51/yaakov-ellis)

Comment: Dang, sad day. Thanks :)